How to force the MacOS PKG to ask the user to move the installer to trash after the install?
does anybody know how to setup the MacOS (M3, Sonoma 14.4.1) installer (pkg file created by pkgbuild/productbuild, contained within dmg) to automatically ask the user to move the installer (the whole wrapping dmg) to trash after the installation?
I did not find any corresponding setting for pkgbuild/productbuild util or within distribution xml. I know that I can do that using post install script but I do not want to follow this path if there exists out of the box solution for this.
I tried to unpack (using pkgutil --expand-full command) some existing installers (third party tools) which are able to fire this dialog but I did not find any corresponding script or settings either. What am I missing? Thank you.

I have got a solution, the file needs to be placed in the download folder and extended attribute com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms has to be set to download URL then the OS fires the desired dialog.
